# Flutter integration_test - initialising and disposing dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive, flutter-integration-test

I’m initializing the app like

```
void main() async {
  await Initializer.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

`Initializer.init()` initializes all dependencies like Firebase Analytics and register things like Hive TypeAdapters.

My sample tests look like:

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  testWidgets(
    'Sample',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await Initializer.init();
      await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
      await tester.tap(find.text('Something'));
      expect(find.text('180 Results'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
  testWidgets(
    'Sample 2',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await Initializer.init();
      await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
      await tester.tap(find.text('Something 2'));
      expect(find.text('180 Results'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```

My problem is that after executing the first test, things that were initialized by `Initializer.init()` aren’t disposed correctly.

1. Is there a way to tell `integration_test` to reset the whole environment every time test is reloaded?
2. Shall I initialize things differently than static `Initializer.init();`
3. Shall I explicitly dispose/unregister all dependencies (sth like `Initializer.dispose()` at the end of every test)? That solution seems to be a nightmare since I'm using many 3rd parties that are not allowing explicit disposing.